# C++ C2280 error: attempting to reference a deleted functions while pushing back into the vector

Tags: c++, visual-c++, game-development, sdl-2

For some reason, when I try pushing into my vector of bricks, I get this error

this is Brick.h

```
class Brick
{
public:
    Brick();
    Brick(int rowSpacing, int columnSpacing, const char* Id, SDL_Renderer* renderer);

    void Hit();
    bool IsHit() { return mIsHit; };
    int GetHealth() { return mCurrentHp; };
    SDL_Texture* GetTexture() { return mTexture; };
    // Objects
    SDL_Rect rect{};

private:
    bool mIsHit;
    int mCurrentHp;
    int mHitPoints;
    int mBreakScore;
    const char* mId;

    SDL_Texture* mTexture;

    // TinyXML
    XMLElement* dataElement;
    XMLDocument mDoc;

    int mBrickWidth = 80;
    int mBrickHeight = 15;
};
```

Bricks.h file:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Brick.h>

class Bricks
{
public:
    // Constructors
    Bricks();

    // Functions
    void Init(SDL_Renderer* renderer);

private:
    // TinyXML
    XMLDocument mDoc;

    // Array of bricks
    std::vector<Brick> brickArr;

    int mBrickWidth = 80;
    int mBrickHeight = 15;
};
```

brick.cpp file:

```
#include "Brick.h"

Brick::Brick() : mIsHit(false) {
}

Brick::Brick(int rowSpacing, int columnSpacing, const char* Id, SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    mDoc.LoadFile("Breakout.xml");

    // Go through every "BrickType" element in the XML file
    dataElement = mDoc.FirstChildElement("Level")->FirstChildElement("BrickTypes");

    for (XMLElement* brickElement = dataElement->FirstChildElement("BrickType");
        brickElement != NULL; brickElement = brickElement->NextSiblingElement())
    {
        if (brickElement->FirstChildElement("Id")->GetText() == std::string(Id)) {
            mId = brickElement->FirstChildElement("Id")->GetText();

            std::stringstream hp(brickElement->FirstChildElement("HitPoints")->GetText());
            hp >> mHitPoints;

            std::stringstream bs(brickElement->FirstChildElement("BreakScore")->GetText());
            bs >> mBreakScore;

            mTexture = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, brickElement->FirstChildElement("Texture")->GetText());
        }
    }

    mCurrentHp = mHitPoints;

    mIsHit = false;

    rect = { rowSpacing, columnSpacing, mBrickWidth, mBrickHeight };
}

void Brick::Hit()
{
    mCurrentHp--;
    if (mCurrentHp == 0) {
        mIsHit = true;
    }
}
```

Now, in the Bricks.cpp file is where i use for loop and try pushing the "Brick" into brickArr vector i made in Bricks.h

Bricks.cpp

```
#include "Bricks.h"
#include <iostream>

Bricks::Bricks()
{
}

void Bricks::Init(SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    brickArr.clear();

    mDoc.LoadFile("Breakout.xml");

    int rows;
    std::stringstream row(mDoc.FirstChildElement("Level")->FirstChildElement("RowCount")->GetText());
    row >> rows;

    int rowSpacing;
    int rowT;
    std::stringstream rowS(mDoc.FirstChildElement("Level")->FirstChildElement("RowSpacing")->GetText());
    rowS >> rowSpacing;
    rowT = rowSpacing;

    int columns;
    std::stringstream col(mDoc.FirstChildElement("Level")->FirstChildElement("ColumnCount")->GetText());
    col >> columns;

    const char* brickP = mDoc.FirstChildElement("Level")->FirstChildElement("Bricks")->GetText();
    std::string brickPlan = brickP;

    // Remove all the unnecessary blanks from the brickPlan
    std::string temp = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < brickPlan.size(); ++i) {
        if ((brickPlan[i] >= 'a' && brickPlan[i] <= 'z') || (brickPlan[i] >= 'A' && brickPlan[i] <= 'Z')) {
            temp = temp + brickPlan[i];
        }
    }
    brickPlan = temp;
    int index = 0;
    
    // Create bricks based on rows, columns and spacings
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

        int columnsSpacing;
        int colT;
        std::stringstream colS(mDoc.FirstChildElement("Level")->FirstChildElement("ColumnSpacing")->GetText());
        colS >> columnsSpacing;
        colT = columnsSpacing;

        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            Brick brick(rowSpacing, columnsSpacing, (const char*)brickPlan[index], renderer);
            brickArr.push_back(brick); // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR HAPPENS
            columnsSpacing = mBrickWidth + columnsSpacing + colT;
            index++;
        }
        rowSpacing = mBrickHeight + rowSpacing + rowT;
    }

}
```

What exactly is causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Have you tried `brickArr.emplace_back(rowSpacing, columnsSpacing, (const char*)brickPlan[index], renderer);`

Comment: @MatG yes I have, but its still not working for some reason. @273K, so I have a `std::vector<Brick> brickArr;` in Bricks.cpp class. But when I try pushing back or emplacing back a Brick i made in the for loop, I get the C2280 error. These are the parameters of the Brick constructor: `Brick(int rowSpacing, int columnSpacing, const char* Id, SDL_Renderer* renderer);`

Comment: Check to see if `XMLDocument` is a copyable type as it's the only member of `Brick` that might not be.  Or provide an online reference for it as the name is a bit too generic for me to go searching for it.

Comment: You probably want `Brick::mDoc` to be `XMLDocument*` (a pointer), just like `dataElement` next to it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you were right, I made it a pointer and it works as it should now, thanks a lot, can you please explain to me why didn't it work normally?

Comment: @Swatheduru As the comment by @RichardCritten suggested, it’s because `XMLDocument` is not copyable, which is required by the default-generated copy constructor of your `Brick` type, which is used by `push_back`.